# Using PIX with a WPF app

Tags: wpf, performance, directx

I have a WPF application that uses an HwndHost to display DirectX 9 content. I'm trying to use the *PIX for Windows* graphics profiler (which comes bundled with the DirectX SDK) to see render states and debug shaders in this DirectX window.

The problem I'm running into is that when I try to do a single-frame capture by pressing F12 in PIX, I sometimes don't get all the draw information for an entire frame. Also, when I try clicking on a DrawPrimitive call in PIX I get an error message saying "A call that previously succeeded failed during playback."

I think the reason for these problems is that WPF also uses DirectX to render all the WPF widgets. It does this on the WPF render thread which is hidden from the user in WPF. It looks like PIX uses calls to IDirect3DDevice9::Present to determine when a frame has ended. The WPF render thread is making calls to IDirect3DDevice9::Present in the middle of a frame of my render, causing PIX to get confused and truncate that frame (and errors when I try to look at DrawPrimitive calls).

Here's a little more information about how my application is set up: I have a WPF application with an HwndHost inside the main window that I use to show some 3D content. In the HwndHost::BuildWindowCore function, I create a window using CreateWindowEx which gives me an hwnd. I then initialize the DirectX 9 device using this hwnd. I then return the hwnd to the HwndHost. I hook up to the CompositionTarget.Render event which calls my unmanaged render function to draw everything in the scene.

I've tried getting this working using the D3DImage control to display my DirectX surface, but I run into the same problem.

It seems to me like the only way to solve this problem is to make sure that the WPF render thread has completely finished before doing a frame capture in PIX. That way, PIX won't be thrown off by any WPF DirectX calls. However, I don't see that there is any way to determine that WPF has finished rendering everything. There is a good post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/693fbedb-efa6-413e-ab66-530c6961d3fb) that explains how to use the Dispatcher.Invoke function to determine when a *single* WPF element has completed rendering, but I need to know when *everything* has finished rendering.

I'm wondering if anybody has successfully set up a WPF application with their own DirectX window and was able to get PIX to work properly. Any help would be appreciated.